# add parameter to dynamic EXECUTE in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have a procedure which contain this piece of code

```
SELECT query INTO query FROM temp_table_test WHERE id = whateverId;

EXECUTE query;
```

My query variable will contain something like

```
CALL Someprocedure (withSomeParameters)
```

How can i make the parameter dynamic in the first proc as they can change time to time and i can't make them static in the variable ?

in t-SQL there is something with

```
sp_executesql
```

But as I'm very new to postgres I don't know where to start.

Comment: You dont need a fuction or procedure; just an ordinary prepared query will do. The syntax for calling it is similar to calling a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you are using pl/pgsql, you can pass parameters with the **USING** clause;

```
EXECUTE query USING $1, $2, $3, ...;
```

for example;

```
query = 'SELECT SUM( "field_a" ) FROM "table" WHERE "field_b" = $1 AND "field_c" = $2';
EXECUTE query USING 5, 10;
```

this will be equal to:

```
SELECT SUM( "field_a" ) FROM "table" WHERE "field_b" = 5 AND "field_c" = 10;
```

Comment: Ok thanks and the query itself, how do i put the parameter ?

something like :

    CALL some procedure ($1, $2, $3)

Comment: in the query text, put $1, $2, $3... to wherever you need the parameters. updating the answer to cover your question